# Python error TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: and ctypes

Tags: python, class, ctypes

I have a DLL library in C, I managed to initialize the functions in python a receive and send data to it. Now I'm trying to reorganize the python code to have all my DLL python functions in one big class.

This is what I have in Visual Studio.

This is Hello.h

```
#pragma once
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdint.h>

#ifdef SOME_API_EXPORTS
#define SOME_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define SOME_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

SOME_API int sum(int a, int b);

SOME_API int mul(int a, int b);

SOME_API void message(void);

#define max_length 63U

typedef struct
{
    uint8_t param1;

    uint32_t param2;

    uint8_t param3;

    uint8_t param4[max_length];

} struct_1;

SOME_API void message_2(struct_1* request);

SOME_API int function_1(uint8_t param_1, uint8_t param_2);
SOME_API int function_2(uint8_t param_1, uint8_t param_2);
```

this is Hello.C

```
#pragma once
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Hello.h"
#include <inttypes.h>

 
int sum(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }

int mul(int a, int b) {
    return a * b;
}

void message(void)
{
    puts("hello from dll\n");
}

SOME_API void message_2(struct_1* request)
{
    printf("data: request=[%d %d %d %s]\n", 
    request->param1, request->param2, request->param3, request->param4);
    //do some processing

}

SOME_API int function_1(uint8_t param_1, uint8_t param_2)
{
    int status;
    //do some processing
    printf("%u  , %u  \n", param_1, param_2);
    status = 1;
    return status;
}

SOME_API int function_2(uint8_t param_1, uint8_t param_2)
{
    int status;
    //do some processing
    printf("%u  , %u  \n", param_1, param_2);
    status = 0;
    return status;
}
```

this is my original python code without the class.

```
import ctypes

test = ctypes.WinDLL('Project.dll')

max_length = 63

class struct_1(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("param1", ctypes.c_ubyte),
                ("param2", ctypes.c_uint32),
                ("param3", ctypes.c_ubyte),
                ("param4", ctypes.c_char * max_length)]

test.message()

##req = struct_1(1, 2 , 3,"test".encode('utf-8'))
##result = test.message_2(ctypes.byref(req))

py_function_1 = test.function_1
py_function_1.argtype = (ctypes.c_uint8,ctypes.c_uint8 )
py_function_1.restype = ctypes.c_int
py_function_1(255,255)

return_val = py_function_1()
print(return_val)

py_function_2 = test.function_2
py_function_2.argtype = (ctypes.c_uint8,ctypes.c_uint8 )
py_function_2.restype = ctypes.c_int
py_function_2(255,255)

return_val = py_function_2()

print(return_val)
```

and this is my python test code trying to implement the class that will contain all my dll function inits. I'm just testing with function_1 and function_2 for now. I will add other functions in the future.

```
import ctypes

test = ctypes.WinDLL('Project.dll')

max_length = 63

class struct_1(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("param1", ctypes.c_ubyte),
                ("param2", ctypes.c_uint32),
                ("param3", ctypes.c_ubyte),
                ("param4", ctypes.c_char * max_length)]

class my_outer_class:

    def __init__(self,py_function_1,py_function_2):

        self.py_function_1 = test.function_1
        self.py_function_1.argtype = (ctypes.c_uint8,ctypes.c_uint8 )
        self.py_function_1.restype = ctypes.c_int

        self.py_function_2 = test.function_2
        self.py_function_2.argtype = (ctypes.c_uint8,ctypes.c_uint8 )
        self.py_function_2.restype = ctypes.c_int

myapi = my_outer_class()
            
result = myapi.py_function_1(255,255)
print(result)

result = myapi.py_function_2(255,255)
print(result)
```

The error I get is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dude\OneDrive\Desktop\Test.py", line 25, in <module>
    myapi = my_outer_class()
TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'py_function_1' and 'py_function_2'
```

I would appreciate any suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: `myapi = my_outer_class()` here `my_outer_class()` is missing parameters

Comment: use should pass py_function_1,py_function_2 to  my_outer_class() like this :
myapi = my_outer_class(py_function_1,py_function_2)

Comment: Thanks guys. I tried your suggestion Milad, but I got the same error. I edited the line to `def __init__(self):` instead of  `def __init__(self,py_function_1,py_function_2):` and it seems to work fine now :o

Comment: Note: it is `.argtypes` (plural) not `.argtype`.

Comment: Hello i have a similar error:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/72968881/19543176 could you please assist me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you define the class's init to have `py_function_1` and `py_function_2` as the constructors. Thus, you should pass the `test.function_1` and `test.function_2` when initializing the object, i.e.

```py
myapi = my_outer_class(test.function_1, test.function_2)
```

and then use it correctly in class' `init`, i.e.

```py
class my_outer_class:

    def __init__(self, py_function_1, py_function_2):

        self.py_function_1 = py_function_1 # change this to use the constructor
        ... # other lines

        self.py_function_2 = py_function_2 # change this to use the constructor
        ... # other lines
```

The solution above means that the user has the ability to supply other callable in the constructor.

Another alternative is to restrict the user to use **only** the one from `.dll`. A possible solution would be the one mentioned in the comments section. However, I don't think this is the best practice because it uses the global scope to find the function. This will be an issue when you tried to scale your script, say, by separating the class in another file. You will need to include non-class code there.

Better solution if you want restrict the user to not altering the `function_1` and `function_2` is to load the `.dll` in the class' `init` instead of in the global scope.

```py
class my_outer_class:

    def __init__(self):
        test = ctypes.WinDLL('Project.dll')
        self.py_function_1 = test.function_1
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will use your solution. So if I have more functions then I will have to add them to `def __init__(self, py_function_1, py_function_2, py_function_3 and so on):` and initialize the object in the same way  `myapi = my_outer_class(test.function_1, test.function_2, test.function_3 and so on)` right? Also, why it doesn't throw an error when I changed the lines to  `def __init__(self):` instead of `def __init__(self,py_function_1,py_function_2):`

Comment: is that the part where you refer to "Another alternative is to restrict the user to use only the one from .dll,  it uses the global scope to find the function"  ?

Comment: Yes, if you are going with my first solution. And yes to your second question, because you have loaded the `.dll` in your main file outside your class, which works but it is not the best practice. All in all, deciding on the first or second solution really depends on your needs. You should go with the second solution if you do not expect custom function/callable.