# TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'dimensions' and 'activations'

Tags: python, function

I'm trying to return some values from a function in a class but it's giving me this error.

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'dimensions' and 'activations'
```

by using:

```
a = SET_MLP()
print(a._update_w_b())
```

so i'm trying to get the values of weights from the below function to use it later but it's giving me that "dimensions" and "activations" are missing.
These lines are the parts of the code which I'm working on:

```
class SET_MLP:
def __init__(self, dimensions, activations,epsilon=20):
    """
    :param dimensions: (tpl/ list) Dimensions of the neural net. (input, hidden layer, output)
    :param activations: (tpl/ list) Activations functions.
    Example of three hidden layer with
    - 3312 input features
    - 3000 hidden neurons
    - 3000 hidden neurons
    - 3000 hidden neurons
    - 5 output classes
    layers -->    [1,        2,     3,     4,     5]
    ----------------------------------------
    dimensions =  (3312,     3000,  3000,  3000,  5)
    activations = (          Relu,  Relu,  Relu,  Sigmoid)
    """
    self.num_layers = len(dimensions)
    self.loss = None
    self.learning_rate = None
    self.momentum=None
    self.weight_decay = None
    self.epsilon = epsilon  # control the sparsity level as discussed in the paper
    self.zeta = None  # the fraction of the weights removed
    self.dimensions=dimensions


    # Weights and biases are initiated by index. For a one hidden layer net you will have a w[1] and w[2]
    self.w = {}
    self.b = {}
    self.pdw={}
    self.pdd={}

    # Activations are also initiated by index. For the example we will have activations[2] and activations[3]
    self.activations = {}
    for i in range(len(dimensions) - 1):
        self.w[i + 1] = createSparseWeights(self.epsilon, dimensions[i], dimensions[i + 1])#create sparse weight matrices
        self.b[i + 1] = np.zeros(dimensions[i + 1])
        self.activations[i + 2] = activations[i]


def _update_w_b(self, index, dw, delta):
    """
    Update weights and biases.
    :param index: (int) Number of the layer
    :param dw: (array) Partial derivatives
    :param delta: (array) Delta error.
    """

    #perform the update with momentum
    if (index not in self.pdw):
        self.pdw[index]=-self.learning_rate * dw
        self.pdd[index] =  - self.learning_rate * np.mean(delta, 0)
    else:
        self.pdw[index]= self.momentum*self.pdw[index]-self.learning_rate * dw
        self.pdd[index] =  self.momentum * self.pdd[index] - self.learning_rate * np.mean(delta, 0)

    self.w[index] += self.pdw[index]-self.weight_decay*self.w[index]
    self.b[index] += self.pdd[index]-self.weight_decay*self.b[index]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify the number of activations and the dimensions when you create the object:

```
a = SET_MLP(activations = x, dimensions = y)
```

Where `x` and `y` are the values for your NN.

This is because `__init__` is the initializer for the class `SET_MLP`.

Alternatively, you can apply a default value like you have done here (**epsilon=20**):

```
def __init__(self, dimensions=x, activations=y, epsilon=20):
```

Comment: i have setten them as per the following: def __init__(self, dimensions= 12317, activations="relu",epsilon=20):
but i got this error : TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len() 
@mfm